# When I click back button WillPopScope is not working in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am using WillPopScope and to navigate I am using Navigator.pushNamed(), so that onWillPop is not working fine, if I remove pushNamed and add pushAndRemoveUntil and make route false it works. But, I do not need like that I need to use pushNamed. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :

```
onWillPop: () async {
        Navigator.pushNamed();
        return false;
      },
```